# seem something of a puzzle

Tags: meaning

I was reading a formal passage (academic) about the animals came across with:

> Play may seem something of a puzzle

My perception was "Play can be considered as puzzle".

I want to know about the structure, ... seem/be/... something of a puzzle/entertainment.

Is it correct to rewrite the sentence as:

1. > Play may seem to be a kind of a puzzle
2. > Play may seem something like a puzzle
3. > Play may seem like a puzzle

?

I am seeking for possible difference when we use **something of a puzzle** rather other options.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To say that X is *something of Y* doesn't mean that it is like Y or appears to be Y; it means that it has some characteristics of *Y* or is *Y* to some degree.

For instance, if I say that "John is something of a perfectionist", I mean that John is not completely a perfectionist, he doesn't demand perfection in everything at all times—but he tends to demand results which approach perfection in many circumstances.

So to say "Play may seem something of a puzzle" means that play may seem to offer some puzzling aspects: there are some things about play that we don't seem to have figured out yet.

Note, by the way, that the collocation *may seem* is usually used to acknowledge the existence of an opinion which the author is going to dispute or disprove:

> John may seem something of a perfectionist, but he's actually pretty easy-going.
>
> Play may seem something of a puzzle, but recent studies by Sartorius (2009) and Undershaft (2012) advance a theory which appears to unite our understanding of play in both animals and man.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've got my answer. I was wondering why we should use such structure if it conveys same information in readers.

Answer (score 1):

"**Something of a puzzle**" basically expresses that [whatever it defines] contains elements that make it a puzzle, but probably only *some elements*.

If we compare that definition with other examples you've given, we can probably distill the difference.

"To be kind of puzzle" (missing 'a', I think) essentially expresses that the entire *whatnot* **is** a puzzle (since there are many kinds of puzzles), is designed to be solved, *everything* about it is like in a puzzle.  "Something *like* a puzzle" has the same meaning as "something *of* a puzzle", so you're very close on that one.  When we say that "*objectA* is something like *objectB*", we essentially say that we are not sure what *objectA* is, it's not really an *objectB*, but rather it is something else, it is of some other class of objects, but looks, smells, acts, very similar to how an *objectB* does.

"Play seems as a puzzle" just doesn't sound right.  The verb *seems* needs no preposition, nor is it a conjunction.

Comment: therefore, are those, "sth of a sth" and "sth like a sth", interchangeable ? always, conveying same information ?

Comment: Only directly interchangeable when the second *sth* represents an entire class of *sths*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to "seem something of a puzzle" just means that it can look like or be considered a puzzle.

There are a few minor problems with your rewordings:

In #2, you need "a" between "like" and "puzzle".

In #3, you need to replace "as" with "like"; "seem as" is not a valid construction.

Comment: I had problem with the structure of "sth of a sth ", where can I read about it ? what does it called in grammar lessons ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a name for it. "[A] of [B]" just means that A belongs to B. So when something "seems [like] something of a puzzle", it looks familiar to something that comes from a puzzle.